# Cursor position in c#

Tags: c#, console, position, text-cursor

I'm just a beginner so sorry if my question is stupid. I'm making program that will ask about rectangle's size (AxB) and will draw it. But I need it to also ask about rectangle's position (X,Y). Is there any way to set a cursor position in c# console app that will work longer than only for an upper part of a rectangle? Or something simple that will make it happen? Here's part of a code:

```
int a;
int b;
int x;
int y;
Console.WriteLine("A");
a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("B");
b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("X");
x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Y");
y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Clear();
Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    Console.Write("*");
Console.Write("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < b - 2; i++)
{
    Console.Write("*");
    for (int k = 0; k < a - 2; k++)
        Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write("*");
    Console.Write("\n");
}
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    Console.Write("*");
Console.Write("\n");
```

Comment: "...that will work longer than only a line?" Huh? I don't understand what you mean here. Also, I don't see you setting the cursor position anywhere in that code. What are you trying to do? Translate the image to the right?

Comment: @itsme86 I'm sorry, English is not my first language. I've edited my question, I hope it's a bit easier to understand now. I'm trying to make a program that will draw a rectangle AxB in position X,Y. But a,b,x,y would be inputed by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by far not the most efficient or elegant solution, but it will work for what you are looking to do:

```
        int a;
        int b;
        int x;
        int y;
        Console.WriteLine("A");
        a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("B");
        b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("X");
        x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Y");
        y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);

        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) //this for will print all the "y" line breaks before your picture prints
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            Console.Write("*");
        Console.Write("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < b - 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) //This for will print x spaces before each line
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.Write("*");
            for (int k = 0; k < a - 2; k++)
                Console.Write(" ");
            Console.Write("*");
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            Console.Write("*");
        Console.Write("\n");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Just needed to print some extra line breaks and spaces in the right places